# process.env values undefined in React app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a web app created using CRA. I have a .env file in the root folder of the app. When the app loads it loads the file and some of the variables are set, but others are undefined. I don't see a problem with the file. Here are the file contents.

```
REACT_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3033/
REACT_APP_URL=http://localhost:3000/
REACT_APP_DB=my_database
REACT_APP_DB_USER=root
REACT_APP_DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Here is what I get when I try to use the .env file variables (output from console.log()).

```
--- App ---> process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL: undefined
--- App ---> process.env.REACT_APP_URL: undefined
--- App ---> process.env.REACT_APP_DB: my_database
--- App ---> process.env.REACT_APP_DB_USER: root
--- App ---> process.env.REACT_APP_DB_PASSWORD: root
```

This looks like a regular shell file where everything after the '=' should be assigned to the variable. So I don't see why 2 of my variables are undefined. That they are URLs shouldn't be an issue, but maybe it is. I've done a lot of digging and haven't found anything that says that it would be a problem.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Mike

Comment: FYI you really shouldn't have access to DB credentials in the client.

Comment: Maybe try renaming the missing variables to some other name. Say for example, `REACT_APP_API_URL` to `REACT_APP_API_HOST` and see if that helps.

Comment: are you possibly overriding them with undefined somewhere else?  seems like it should be working otherwise.  as a test you could put in MY_FAKE_URL=http://fake.url

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having cache issues. Once I removed the spaces around the '=' in each line, something not shown in my question, and flushed my cache it worked. Ctrl-F5 didn't affect the issue, which is strange.